# Is it safe to reassign std::map::value_type&?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

If I have a map with a set of exist key-value pairs, is it safe for me to reassign direct to an iterator? For example:

```
bool switchIf(const std::string& key, Widget& widget)
{
    WidgetMap::iterator iter = _widgets.find(key);
    if(_widgets.end() != iter)
    { 
        iter->second = widget;
    }
    return (_widgets.end() != iter);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is completely safe. `iter->second` is nothing, but a reference to the value in the map.